# Regular Expression to match the word boundary but exclude the word if it has any prefix or suffix

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to figure out the Regular Expression to match the word boundary but exclude the word if it has any prefix OR suffix. I'm able to find the word using word boundary, but it is not excluding the certain patterns of the word.

The way I'm using is :

```
\bfindword\b
```

Since I'm using \b , it is not eliminating some patterns. Examples,

```
.findword
findword.
/findword
findword/
.findword.
foo.findword.bar
```

I'm trying this in Notepad++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookarounds to precise the boundaries:

```
\b(?<![./])findword\b(?![./])
  ^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?<![./])` lookbehind will fail the match if there is a `.` or `/` before the word, and the `(?![./])` lookahead will fail the match if there is a `.` or `/` after the word.

[image]